# Ecto build multiple assoc

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Currently working on Phoenix project using Ecto + Postgres. When creating a comment, as comment `belongs_to` both User and Article, is there a way to build multiple associations to generate one changeset?

Something like this pseudocode

```
comment_changeset = build_assoc(article, :comment) 
                 |> build_assoc(user, :comment)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Justin mentioned, you can use `put_assoc` to do that, so off the top of my head I think something like this should work.

```
comment_changeset =
  article
  |> Ecto.build_assoc(:comment)
  |> Ecto.Changeset.change()
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:user, user)
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how your application is setup, you will want to use either [`cast_assoc/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3) or [`put_assoc/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4)

The relevant part from the documentation is

> In other words, `cast_assoc/3` is useful when the associated data is managed alongside the parent struct, all at once. If each side of the association is managed separately, it is preferable to use `put_assoc/3` and directly instruct Ecto how the association should look like.