# Create nested associations

Tags: elixir, associations, ecto

Please consider the following schema:

```
schema "businesses" do
  ...
  has_many :contacts, Contact
  has_many :conversations, Conversation
  ...
end
```

```
schema "contacts" do
  ...
  belongs_to :business, Business
  has_one :conversation, Conversation
  ...
end
```

```
schema "conversations" do
  ...
  belongs_to :business, Business
  belongs_to :contact, Contact
  has_many :messages, Message
  ...
end
```

```
schema "messages" do
  belongs_to :conversation, Conversation
  belongs_to :contact, Contact
end
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42761363/1911755) shows how one can put two associations on a struct.

I've followed that pattern and it works nicely.

```
def create_conversation(%{business: business, contact: contact, message: message} = attrs) do
  business
  |> Ecto.build_assoc(:conversations)
  |> Ecto.Changeset.change()
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:contact, contact)
  |> Repo.insert()
end
```

However, I'm wondering what the idiomatic way would be to also create a `message` (which is an association of the newly created `conversation` above) so that it would be associated with this newly created `conversation`. Does it make sense to do this in one `Repo.insert()` call or not? How would someone experienced in Elixir / Ecto approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this works!

```
def create_conversation(%{business: business, contact: contact, message: message} = attrs) do
  business
  |> Ecto.build_assoc(:conversations)
  |> Ecto.Changeset.change()
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:contact, contact)
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:messages, [%Message{body: message.body}])
  |> Repo.insert()
end
```